# Download a file to heroku process it and send as an attachment

Tags: python, django, heroku, amazon-s3

I'm trying to do the following:

1. Download a pdf file from S3 to my heroku.
2. Process the pdf.
3. Email the pdf as an attachment.

Is it possible? If yes, could you please give me a tip how?
I'm running Django and pdf is about 1MB.

This is my processing part:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader 
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.colors import HexColor
import os, sys
import requests
from io import BytesIO

URL = "https://domainname.com/sample.pdf"
response=requests.get(URL)
p = BytesIO(response.content)
p.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)

def watermark_product(watermark_text, input_file_path, output_file_path):

    c = canvas.Canvas("watermark.pdf") 
    c.setFont("Helvetica", 24)
    c.setFillGray(0.5,0.5)
    c.saveState() 
    c.translate(500,100) 
    c.rotate(45) 
    c.drawCentredString(0, 300, watermark_text) 
    c.restoreState() 
    c.save() 

    input_file = PdfFileReader(input_file_path) 
    output_writer = PdfFileWriter() 
    total_pages = input_file.getNumPages()

    for single_page in range(total_pages):
        page = input_file.getPage(single_page)
        watermark = PdfFileReader("watermark.pdf")
        page.mergePage(watermark.getPage(0))
        output_writer.addPage(page)

    with open(output_file_path, "wb") as outputStream:
        output_writer.write(outputStream)
    os.remove("watermark.pdf")

watermark_product('testtesatd', p, 'w1.pdf')
```

EDIT:

I've managed to keep the pdf file in memory.

Comment: Have you tried doing this yourself? What is the specific problem that you're encountering? Are you having trouble retrieving the file? Processing it? Emailing it?

Comment: My main issue is downloading a file to heroku

Comment: Do you have its URL? What kind of processing are you trying to do on it?

Comment: I'm storing the pdf files on S3. I need to put a watermark with order id on it.

Comment: You want to add the watermark after saving the file? Are you planning to store it back to the same filename? Would it make more sense to add the watermark before saving the file the first time?

Comment: I'm storing plain pdfs on S3. When a customer purchase a pdf it triggers the app to download the pdf put the watermark and send it back to customer.

Comment: Okay, and how does your watermarking process work? Do you need to load the PDF into memory? Do you need to pass in a filename?

Comment: I've updated the topic.

Comment: Have you tried simply passing in the file's S3 URL as `input_file_path`?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting `FileNotFoundError` even though the file is public.

Comment: Does your edit mean that you've solved this problem yourself?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. I've got another puzzle to solve but that's for another topic. Thanks Chris for help.